# how to some cell typing event consume in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

how to do this table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SSGs.jpg]

I want to 'title 1' column cell text equal "0.00" 'title 2' column cell can not type. (only same row).

I want to 'title 1' column cell text not equal "0.00" 'title 2' column cell can type. (only same row).

How to do this. please help.

Comment: can i help with video?

Answer (score 0):

In your TableModel, implement method isCellEditable so that it returns true if you want the cell to be editable, false otherwise.

Example:

```
boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return true;
        case 1:
            {
                Object col0 = getValueAt(int rowIndex, 0);
                if (col0 instanceof Number && ((Number)col0).doubleValue() == 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain with video.